# Delete from database with button doesn't have any affect?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to delete something from the Database. After that didn't work, I tried to simply echo $id. But this did not work either.

```
if (isset($_POST['aktion']) and $_POST['aktion']=='loeschen') {
    $id = "";
    if (isset($_POST['nummer'])) {
        $id = trim($_POST['nummer']);
        echo 'Hello '.$id.'!';

    }
}
```

I use the same method to fill the database which works.

This is the code for the button:

```
<input type="hidden" name="aktion" value="loeschen">
<input type="submit" value="loeschen">
```

I used the same code on the buttons to add data to the database and it works great.

Comment: It seems to me that `isset($_POST['nummer']` will always be false if you  take only this code. There is no input field with `name="nummer"`

Comment: Share full html form to check what is  $_POST['nummer'] contain